# How to control d3.format with SI-prefix?

Tags: d3.js

I can display `1,500,000` as `1.5M` using `d3.format(".2s")(1500000)`, but how can I display `500,000` as `.5M`?

Using `d3.format(".2s")(500000)` results in `500k`.

Also, `d3.format(".2s")(5000000)` results in `5.0M`, but `d3.format(".2s")(10000000)` results in `10M`. Is there a format I can specify to get both `5.0M` and `10.0M`?

Answer (score 2):

The first isn't possible directly with D3. The idea of the SI prefix is that you always have a non-zero value in front of the point. Similarly, the second thing you're asking for isn't possible either, as the precision (the number after the dot in the format) has no effect when using SI formatting.

It sounds like the easiest thing to do in your case would be to create a millions formatter manually, i.e. divide all the numbers by a million and add the "M" at the end yourself. This would then allow you to use one of the other formatters that allows you to specify the precision.

You may also find the [`d3.formatPrefix()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#d3_formatPrefix) useful, which will give you the SI prefix for a given number.

Comment: I have a question here (http://stackoverflow.com/q/41385010/1735836) you might be able to help me with.